version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
I updated Flutter and got this error, what should I do? I changed the Kotlin version, it still didn't work, how can I solve this problem?
Tried most versions and the problem still exists
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}

plugins {
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
  id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
 // START: FlutterFire Configuration
  id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
  // END: FlutterFire Configuration
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
  }

include ":app"

These pictures illustrate the problem.




what is the flutter version your are using?. Cause this is a common issue for version 3.24.0

Flutter 3.24.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5874a72aa4 (6 days ago) • 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
Engine • revision c9b9d5780d
Tools • Dart 3.5.1 • DevTools 2.37.2

I know that is not the most correct answer but for now you can just downgrade your flutter version to 3.22.3
